# Change output language in Flash CS4?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

I'm using Flash CS4 and almost everything is in english, except for errors in Output window...

Like:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2180: É ilegal mover o conteúdo AVM1 (AS1 ou AS2) para outra parte de displayList quando ele tiver sido carregado para o conteúdo AVM2 (AS3).
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
    at com.gabrielbianconi.web::ContentLoader$/loadComplete()
```

I would like to get these errors in english... Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try reinstalling the app with your computer set to an English locale.

Another idea, if you're on the mac you could try right clicking on the application and do show package contents. This folder would contain some of the localization settings. You could try replacing the contents of `Contents/Resources/it.lproj` with someone elses english folder. If you try this, back up your copy of Flash because you could break it and I am not responsible for what happens!